# Increasing functions $f,g$, and asymptotic of $\max(f(n),g(n))$

Tags: asymptotics

I'm new to introduction to algorithms and asymptotic analysis.

I'm trying to prove/disprove this:

> Let $f,g\colon\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ be increasing functions, i.e. such that  $(f(n+1)>f(n)$ and $g(n+1)>g(n))$ for all $n$.
>
> Define $h\colon\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ as follows: $h(n)=\max(f(n),g(n))$ for each $n \in N$.
>
> Does it necessarily follows that $h=O(f)$ or $h=O(g)$?

Intuitively, it looks true for me but I have no idea how to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Not necessarily.**

For simplicity, I'll replace the strict monotonicity recquirement by $f,g$ non-decreasing. *(It does not change anything, you can always add a very small slope to make them increasing.)*

Let $f$ be defined by
$$f(n) = 2^{(\lfloor \log_2 n\rvert)^2}$$
i.e. $f$ is constant on each $[2^k, 2^{k+1})$ with value $2^{k^2}$.

Now, let $g$ be defined as the piecewise constant function, constant on each $[2^{3k}, 2^{3(k+1)})$ with value $2^{(3k+1)^2}$.

We have

- $f<g$ on each $[2^{3k}, 2^{3k+1})$
- $f=g$ on each $[2^{3k+1}, 2^{3k+2})$
- $f>g$ on each $[2^{3k+2}, 2^{3k+3})$.

Moreover, the ratio $\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}$ is then either
$2^{(3k)^2-(3k+1)^2}= 2^{-(6k+1)}$, $1$, or $2^{(3k+2)^2-(3k+1)^2}= 2^{3(2k+1)}$. When $k\to\infty$, this shows that $\frac{f}{\max(f,g)}$ and $\frac{g}{\max(f,g)}$ both get arbitrarily close to $0$ and $\infty$.

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret Yes, that's what I tried to convey in " (It does not change anything, you can always add a very small slope to make them increasing.)". Add any strictly (small) increasing function to both $f$ and $g$ to get them to be increasing.

Comment: Apologies, somehow I missed that.